# Filter nested array of objects and get total with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-loops, array-filter

I have an array of objects like below:

```
     const data = [
     {
        "order_id":38795,
        "order_type":"Music",
        "date":"2021-08-14",
        "name":"Concert",
        "tickets":[
           {
              "id":9,
              "ticket_type":"Priority",
              "quantity":2,
              "price":25,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           },
           {
              "id":10,
              "ticket_type":"Priority",
              "quantity":1,
              "price":10,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":0,
                 "Children":1,
              }
           },
           {
              "id":10,
              "ticket_type":"Standard",
              "quantity":3,
              "price":15,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "order_id":84874,
        "order_type":"Film",
        "date":"2021-08-14",
        "name":"Adventure",
        "tickets":[
           {
              "id":7,
              "ticket_type":"Standard",
              "quantity":1,
              "price":20,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  ];
```

I need to be able to get the total quantity of Adult tickets for Music order_types.

In this case the answer would be 5 (2 * Adult Priority and 3 * Adult Standard)

I've started by using the array `filter` to create a new array that only includes the 'Music' `order_type`

```
const musicOrders = data.filter((order) => {
    return order.order_type == 'Music'
});
```

In regards to adding the quantity fields, I think the array `reduce` will multiply the quantity in a loop.

```
.reduce((total, ticket) => {
    return total + ticket.quantity;
}, 0)
```

But I'm not sure how I can first filter the `data` array to both

```
order_type = "Music"
ticket.detail.Adults = 1 / true
```

And then get the quantities, all in one function?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's in one function or two? I mean, you could write a single function that calls the two functions. Then it would be one function call. And what have you gained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.find()` to search for "Music". 
Then `Array.prototype.reduce()` like so:

```js
const data = [
     {
        "order_id":38795,
        "order_type":"Music",
        "date":"2021-08-14",
        "name":"Concert",
        "tickets":[
           {
              "id":9,
              "ticket_type":"Priority",
              "quantity":2,
              "price":25,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           },
           {
              "id":10,
              "ticket_type":"Priority",
              "quantity":1,
              "price":10,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":0,
                 "Children":1,
              }
           },
           {
              "id":10,
              "ticket_type":"Standard",
              "quantity":3,
              "price":15,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           }
        ]
     },
     {
        "order_id":84874,
        "order_type":"Film",
        "date":"2021-08-14",
        "name":"Adventure",
        "tickets":[
           {
              "id":7,
              "ticket_type":"Standard",
              "quantity":1,
              "price":20,
              "detail":{
                 "Adults":1,
                 "Children":0,
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  ];

  
  const res = data.find(item => item.order_type === 'Music').tickets.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc += curr.quantity * curr.detail.Adults;
    return acc;
  }, 0);

  console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` as follow:

The top-level reduce call checks for the object with `order_type == 'Music'` and the nested reduce call counts the quantities when the attr `Adults > 0`.

```js
const data = [     {        "order_id":38795,        "order_type":"Music",        "date":"2021-08-14",        "name":"Concert",        "tickets":[           {              "id":9,              "ticket_type":"Priority",              "quantity":2,              "price":25,              "detail":{                 "Adults":1,                 "Children":0,              }           },           {              "id":10,              "ticket_type":"Priority",              "quantity":1,              "price":10,              "detail":{                 "Adults":0,                 "Children":1,              }           },           {              "id":10,              "ticket_type":"Standard",              "quantity":3,              "price":15,              "detail":{                 "Adults":1,                 "Children":0,              }           }        ]     },     {        "order_id":84874,        "order_type":"Film",        "date":"2021-08-14",        "name":"Adventure",        "tickets":[           {              "id":7,              "ticket_type":"Standard",              "quantity":1,              "price":20,              "detail":{                 "Adults":1,                 "Children":0,              }           }        ]     }  ],
      countQty = (at, {quantity, detail: {Adults}}) => at + (Adults > 0 ? quantity : 0),
      result = data.reduce((a, {tickets, order_type}) => {
         return a + (order_type == "Music" ? tickets.reduce(countQty, 0) : 0);
      }, 0);
  
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it using double [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) which would fulfill your condition of only having to call one (parent) function.

I'm afraid it's really not possible to do this by just using one single function since there are nested (=multiple) arrays that need to be iterated through.

```js
const data= [{order_id:38795,order_type:"Music",date:"2021-08-14",name:"Concert",tickets:[{id:9,ticket_type:"Priority",quantity:2,price:25,detail:{Adults:1,Children:0,},},{id:10,ticket_type:"Priority",quantity:1,price:10,detail:{Adults:0,Children:1,},},{id:10,ticket_type:"Standard",quantity:3,price:15,detail:{Adults:1,Children:0,},},],},{order_id:84874,order_type:"Film",date:"2021-08-14",name:"Adventure",tickets:[{id:7,ticket_type:"Standard",quantity:1,price:20,detail:{Adults:1,Children:0,}}]}];

const result = data.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
  (acc +=
    curr.order_type === "Music" &&
    curr.tickets.reduce(
      (acc, curr) => acc + curr.detail.Adults * curr.quantity,
      0
    )),
  0
);

console.log(result);
```